# How to eliminate a day and a day after it based on date observations in another table?

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, stata

I have Tables 1 and 2, which have the `name` and `date` variables.

I want to remove observations in Table 1 with the same `name` and `date` in Table 2. In addition, for the same `name` and `date` between Table 1 and 2, I want to delete the next date after it in Table 1.

**Table 1:**

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 name long date
"A" 17659
"A" 17724
"A" 17900
"A" 17901
"A" 18086
"A" 18102
"A" 18239
"B" 17659
"B" 17662
"B" 17669
"B" 17676
"B" 17684
"B" 17701
"B" 18026
"C" 18177
"C" 18187
"C" 18195
"C" 18219
"C" 18235
"C" 18250
"C" 18391
"C" 18391
"C" 18392
end
format %d date
```

**Table 2:**

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 name long date
"A" 17724
"A" 17900
"A" 18102
"B" 17659
"B" 17669
"B" 17701
"B" 18087
"C" 18187
"C" 18235
"C" 18250
end
format %d date
```

The expected result is the following:

```
+------+-----------+
| name |   date    |
+------+-----------+
| A    | 7-May-08  |
| A    | 8-Jul-09  |
| B    | 1-Jun-08  |
| C    | 7-Oct-09  |
| C    | 18-Nov-09 |
| C    | 10-May-10 |
+------+-----------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will give you the desired output as long as there are **no duplicate** entries:

```
clear

input str4 name1 long date1
"A" 17659
"A" 17724
"A" 17900
"A" 17901
"A" 18086
"A" 18102
"A" 18239
"B" 17659
"B" 17662
"B" 17669
"B" 17676
"B" 17684
"B" 17701
"B" 18026
"C" 18177
"C" 18187
"C" 18195
"C" 18219
"C" 18235
"C" 18250
"C" 18391
"C" 18391
"C" 18392
end
```

---

```
input str4 name2 long date2
"A" 17724
"A" 17900
"A" 18102
"B" 17659
"B" 17669
"B" 17701
"B" 18087
"C" 18187
"C" 18235
"C" 18250
end
```

---

```
format %d date1
format %d date2

local obs = _N

generate todrop1 = 0

forvalues i = 1 / `obs' {
    forvalues j = 1 / `obs' {
        replace todrop1 = 1 in `i' if name1[`i'] == name2[`j'] & ///
                                      date1[`i'] == date2[`j']
    }
}

generate todrop2 = 0

forvalues i = 1 / `obs' {
    if todrop1[`i'] == 1 {
        replace todrop2 = 1 in `=`i'+1'
    }   
}

list name1 date1 if todrop1 == 0 & todrop2 == 0
```

---

In this particular case, `C 09may2010` comes up in the output because it exists twice in `name1`:

```
     +-------------------+
     | name1       date1 |
     |-------------------|
  1. |     A   07may2008 |
  5. |     A   08jul2009 |
 12. |     B   01jun2008 |
 15. |     C   07oct2009 |
 18. |     C   18nov2009 |
     |-------------------|
 22. |     C   09may2010 |
 23. |     C   10may2010 |
     +-------------------+
```

Indeed, by removing the duplicate entry `"C" 18391` from `name1` and re-running the code we get:

```
    +-------------------+
    | name1       date1 |
    |-------------------|
 1. |     A   07may2008 |
 5. |     A   08jul2009 |
12. |     B   01jun2008 |
15. |     C   07oct2009 |
18. |     C   18nov2009 |
    |-------------------|
22. |     C   10may2010 |
    +-------------------+
```

If you have duplicate entries in your data, you can first use the `duplicates` command to get rid of them *assuming this is an appropriate thing to do* in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I get this because I can't reproduce your result. The technique here may help, however.

```
clear

input str4 name long date
"A" 17659
"A" 17724
"A" 17900
"A" 17901
"A" 18086
"A" 18102
"A" 18239
"B" 17659
"B" 17662
"B" 17669
"B" 17676
"B" 17684
"B" 17701
"B" 18026
"C" 18177
"C" 18187
"C" 18195
"C" 18219
"C" 18235
"C" 18250
"C" 18391
"C" 18391
"C" 18392
end

format %d date
gen table = 1 
save table1 , replace
```

---

```
clear

input str4 name long date
"A" 17724
"A" 17900
"A" 18102
"B" 17659
"B" 17669
"B" 17701
"B" 18087
"C" 18187
"C" 18235
"C" 18250
end

format %d date
gen table = 2 
append using table1 

bysort name date (table) : gen todrop = table == 1 & table[1] != table[_N] 
bysort table name date : replace todrop = 1 if todrop[_n-1] == 1 
by table name date : replace todrop = 1 if todrop[_n-1] == 1 & date == date[_n-1] 

drop if todrop
```

---

```
list, sepby(table) 

     +-----------------------------------+
     | name        date   table   todrop |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |    A   07may2008       1        0 |
  2. |    A   04jan2009       1        0 |
  3. |    A   08jul2009       1        0 |
  4. |    A   08dec2009       1        0 |
  5. |    B   10may2008       1        0 |
  6. |    B   24may2008       1        0 |
  7. |    B   01jun2008       1        0 |
  8. |    B   09may2009       1        0 |
  9. |    C   07oct2009       1        0 |
 10. |    C   25oct2009       1        0 |
 11. |    C   18nov2009       1        0 |
 12. |    C   09may2010       1        0 |
 13. |    C   09may2010       1        0 |
 14. |    C   10may2010       1        0 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 15. |    A   11jul2008       2        0 |
 16. |    A   03jan2009       2        0 |
 17. |    A   24jul2009       2        0 |
 18. |    B   07may2008       2        0 |
 19. |    B   17may2008       2        0 |
 20. |    B   18jun2008       2        0 |
 21. |    B   09jul2009       2        0 |
 22. |    C   17oct2009       2        0 |
 23. |    C   04dec2009       2        0 |
 24. |    C   19dec2009       2        0 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```